# How to mount host file when using Singularity

Tags: docker, containers, singularity-container

I am using Singularity, a container-based software similar to docker.

In docker, when you are trying to mount a host system file/folder to containers, you need:

```
docker run -v /host/system/folder:/container/system/folder image_name [command]
```

I was wondering how to do the same thing in Singularity, according to its documentation(honestly, not too much tutorials available online) and my own understanding, it should be like:

```
singularity run -B /host/system/folder:/container/system/folder image_name [command]
```

I tried but it can not generate what I expected, so my question is what's the correct way to mount a host system file to singularity container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct way to do it, but depending on the version of singularity and your kernel (i.e., overlay not enabled, common in RHEL/CentOS 6) you may need to have a pre-existing folder at that location to mount.

It may be a typo, but your singularity statement is also incorrectly formed. `singularity run -B /foo:/bar image_name some_cmd some_opt` will not run `some_cmd some_opt`, it will execute the `%runscript` block from the definition file. If you want to specify the command to run in the container, use the `singularity exec ...` form. The [documentation goes into more detail](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/quick_start.html#interact-with-images) on the differences between the various subcommands.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have a follow up question if you don't mind me asking (I am really a beginner of using Singularity), if overlay is not enabled, is there any way I could check which folder is pre-existing on container's file system? Like you mentioned in the answer, how do I know if '/bar' is a pre-existing folder or not? Hoping my question make sense and much appreciated for your help!

Comment: `singularity shell image.sif` puts you in an interactive shell session. You can then move around the file system and look around. It will try to mount `$PWD` and `$HOME`, but just gives a warning if it is unable to do so